# Converting string to argument in bash

Tags: bash, quotes, xargs

I want to form an argument for tail using xargs.

`"string" | xargs -I '{}' tail -F  *{}*`

This results in 
`tail  "*{}*"`
which does not work. How do I remove the quotes and turn it into a valid argument for `tail`?
i.e. `tail *string*`

Comment: Doesn't `"string" |` result in a `bash: string: command not found` error? Do you have a command named `string`? `This results in` How do you know? How did you check that it results in that? `How do I remove the quotes` Who added the qoutes? How were they added? `turn it into a valid argument for tail?` Is `"*{}*"` and invalid argument? Do you really have a filename named literally `*string*` that you want tail from? Or do you expect `*string*` to __expand__ to list of filenames that match the globulation pattern? `which does not work` Is there an error message?

Comment: @manu190466 I suspect that `*` symbols in your comment have been interpreted as markup - please can you check the formatting (e.g. putting the code inside backticks).

Comment: Maybe what you want is : `echo "string" | xargs -I '{}' tail -F {}`

Comment: @alaniwi thank you for your comment, I actually had problems with my formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` is interpreted by Bourne shell (pathname expansion) at the moment your command is parsed, before it is actually executed, NOT at the moment `tail` is executed.

If you want that the command built by `xargs` be subject to `bash`'s pathname expansion, you need to execute `bash`:

```
echo "string" | xargs -I '{}' bash -c "tail -F *'{}'*"
```

Security issue: if you don't have control over the file names sent to `xargs`, then with specially crafted filenames, you may end up inadvertently executing hamrful commands.